# Rails Filter values from hash with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have this following hash and I need to filter out movies (movie name is the hash key) if they are of certain genre. The problem is that is with the association.

```
{"Kaze no tani no Naushika"=>
  {:count=>127, 
   :genres=>#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy 
   [#<Genre genre_id: 911, name: "Action", ParentID: nil>, 
    #<Genre genre_id: 912, name: "Adventure", ParentID: nil>, 
    #<Genre genre_id: 913, name: "Animation", ParentID: nil>, 
    #<Genre genre_id: 923, name: "Fantasy", ParentID: nil>, 
    #<Genre genre_id: 936, name: "Science Fiction", ParentID: nil>]>},** 
 "Mononoke-hime"=>
  {:count=>53, 
   :genres=>#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy 
   [#<Genre genre_id: 912, name: "Adventure", ParentID: nil>, 
    #<Genre genre_id: 913, name: "Animation", ParentID: nil>, 
    #<Genre genre_id: 923, name: "Fantasy", ParentID: nil>]>}, 
 "Sen to Chihiro no kamikakushi"=>
  {:count=>102, 
   :genres=>#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy 
   [#<Genre genre_id: 912, name: "Adventure", ParentID: nil>, 
    #<Genre genre_id: 913, name: "Animation", ParentID: nil>, 
    #<Genre genre_id: 921, name: "Family", ParentID: nil>]>},...
```

I use rails 4.0.0. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should do this at the ActiveRecord level, if possible.

Comment: Putting this has aside for the moment, can you give the basics of your Genre, and presumably Movie classes with schema snippet. Also, expand on the behaviour your are wanting, with some useful example(s).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of [Hash#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select) and [Enumerable#find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
adventure_movies = movies.select do |movie_name, movie_attrs|
  movie_attrs[:genres].find { |genre| genre.name == 'Adventure' }
end
```